# How to show that Hilbert function of points in projective space is constant for large values $\in N$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Recall that for $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ an algebraic set with homogeneous coordinate ring $Γ(X) = k[x_1, ..., x_{n+1}]/I(X)$, the Hilbert function of $X$ is a function $h_{X }: \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$ defined
as: $h_{X}(m)$ = dim$_k(Γ(X)_m)$.

> Let $X ⊂ P^n$ be a set of $d$ points. Show that $h_{X}(m) = d$ for $m \geq d-1$.

By explicit computation, I've checked this result for $d=1,2,3,4,...$ but i'm unable to prove this for arbitrary $d$ points. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fix a linear function $L$ that doesn't vanish on any point of $X$. We have a map $\phi: \Gamma(X)_m\rightarrow \prod_{p\in X}{k}$ that sends a function $f$ to the value of $\frac{f}{L^m}$ at each point $p\in X$. As said in the comment below, the purpose of $L$ is to make $\phi$ well-defined, as scaling the coordinates of $p\in X$ will scale $f(p)$. By definition of $\Gamma(X)$, this is injective, so $h_X(m)\leq d$ in general.

If we are given a value of $m\geq d-1$, and want to show $h_X(m)=d$, it suffices to show $\phi$ is surjective. To do this, it suffices to find, for each $p_{0}\in X$, a function $f\in \Gamma(X)_m$ that vanishes on $p\in X$ for $p\neq p_0$, but does not vanish on $p_0$.

To do this, pick hyperplanes $\{L_p=0\}$ for each $p\in X$ such that $L_p$ passes through $p$ but not any other point in $X$. If $m=d-1$, we can let $f=\prod_{p\neq p_0}{L_p}$. If $m>d-1$, we can multiply $\prod_{p\neq p_0}{L_p}$ by any function not vanishing on $p_0$.

Harris' *First Course in Algebraic Geometry* has a chapter which covers this and a bit more.

Comment: Dear Dtseng, your map $\phi$ doesn't make sense because points $p\in X$ have many sets of coordinates and so "values" do not exist . For example, if $n=1, X=\{p=(1:0)\}\subset \mathbb P^1, I(X)=(x_2), \Gamma(X)=k[x_1]$,  what is the value of $2x_1$ at  $p=(1:0)=(17:0)$ ?

Comment: @Georges thanks for the correction! I think we can fix this problem by working in a trivialization of $O(m)$, for example by picking a hyperplane not passing through any point in $X$ cut out by $L$ and taking $f(x)/L(x)^m$. Unless somebody answers beforehand, I will update in a couple days when I can type on a computer instead of a cell phone.

Comment: Okay, I think it's fixed now.